# Find out minimum value of specific columns in a row in MS Excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013

My table in Excel looks something like this:

```
abcd    67  94  52  89 24
efgh    23  45  93  54 34
ijkl    64  83  23  45 92
mnop    34  45  10  66 53
```

This is a student database containing marks obtained in various subjects. I need to calculate the percentage in each row such that out of 5 subjects, the first subject is always included with other 3 subject with maximum marks.

```
Example: abcd 67 94 52 89 24 75.5%
```

Here `75.5%=(67+94+52+89)/4=302/4=75.5` where `24` being the lowest has been excluded and `67` has to be taken even if it were the least.

What I require is the least(excluding the first column, of course) of all the columns in that particular row, so that I can sum all the marks and subtract this least marks and finally use it to calculate the percentage.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to adjust this for your columns, but if you sum the entire range, then subtract the min value after, do a count of the range then subtract one from that, you will be able to get the average.

This code is using the 4 values from column B through F and the 4 values are: 67    94  52  89  24... which results in 75.5

```
=(SUM(B3:F3)-MIN(C3:F3))/(COUNT(B3:F3)-1)
```

Comment: It should be ‘MIN(C3:F3)’ - OP states the first result column needs to be taken, even if it is the lowest value

Comment: Must have clarified after posted with the edit, i'll change. Thanks

Comment: @BenjaminCharais Thanks, I tried and it worked well and Thank you PTD  :)